# CakePHP 3: how to make all actions always rendering to the same template?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building an API project on which the templates always have the same code:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($return);
```

The common way is creating folders correspondenting with my actions on Template folder, but the ctp files are all equal. How could I use `render()` function pointing always to the same file?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the doc https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: I didn't know about that. Reading.

Comment: @AmanRawat that's the answer. I solved using `$this->set(compact('return')); $this->set('_serialize', ['return']);` on controller. Thank you. Please, answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: You can answer to your own question. How you solved the problem  :)